# Object of class Produit could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\grafiPhp\crud php\classes\produit.php on line 32

Tags: php

produit.php  I receive an error on update function.  I haven't been able to find any solution really I need your help.

```
public function update($id){

    $sql="UPDATE $this ->table SET titre= :titre 
    description=:descr, stock=:stock WHERE id=:id";//here where the error appear

    $stmt=db::prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':titre',$this->titre);
    $stmt->bindParam(':descr',$this->description);
    $stmt->bindParam(':stock',$this->stock);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);

     return $stmt->execute();
}
```

here is my index.php code where I retrieve data from form

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $titre=$_POST['titre'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];

    $stock=$_POST['stock'];


    $produit->setTitre($titre);
    $produit->setDescription($description);
    $produit->setStock($stock);
    if($produit->update($id)){
        echo"<p> success</p>";
    }
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about the $this in `$sql="UPDATE $this ->table SET titre`.
At the very least the space between $this and ->something ticks it off, trying to use the objecte/instance referenced by $this in a string context instead of accessing the property `table` of that instance.

For clarity use the [curly braces syntax](http://docs.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.complex) like

```
$sql="UPDATE {$this->table} SET titre= :titre 
    description=:descr, stock=:stock WHERE id=:id";
```

or [sprintf()](http://docs.php.net/sprintf) ...or [concatenation](http://docs.php.net/language.operators.string), if you must.